# Finding a max value in a list that is also a multiple of another parameter using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, max

e.g

```
l = [1, 4, 5, 9, 11]
print(max_multiples_list(l, 3)) 
>>> 9
```

my code seems to work but is failing a hidden case i'm guessing maybe when the list is empty?

```
def max_multiples_list(lst,m):
if len(lst) == 1:
    if lst[0] % m != 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return lst[0]
else:
    n = max_multiples_list(lst[1:],m)
    if lst[0] % 2 == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return n if n > lst[0] and n%m == 0 else lst[0]
```

Comment: What's the point of `if lst[0] % 2 == 0:`?

Comment: Shouldn't you just do `return n if lst[0]%m or n > lst[0] else lst[0]` in the else clause, without any of the other weird stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code and leave your feedbacks if you have any issues with it. (PS: remove the comment before `print(a, v_max)` in order to trace the recursion):

**NB:**

- If the return is equal to `0`: There isn't any max value found in the input's list.
- If the return is `None`: The input's list is empty

The code:

```
def max_multiple(a, number, v_max=0):
        # Debug
        # print(a, v_max)
        if len(a) is 0:
            return None

        v_max = a[0] if a[0] % number is 0 and a[0] > v_max else v_max

        return v_max if len(a) is 1 else max_multiple(a[1:], number, v_max)

# Some tests
l = [1, 4, 5, 9, 11]
print(max_multiple(l, 3))

l = [1, 4, 5, 9, 11, 15, 16, 21, 30, 21, 3, 15]
print(max_multiple(l, 3))

l = [1, 4, 5, 9, 11, 15, 16, 21, 30, 21, 3, 30, 60]
print(max_multiple(l, 3))

l = [4]
print(max_multiple(l, 3))

l = [12]
print(max_multiple(l, 3))

l = []
print(max_multiple(l, 3))
```

Output:

```
9
30
60
0
12
None
```